# decoding bytes to ipaddress

Tags: java, arrays

I have a java application that listens to upd packets on a socket. I send it raw bytes that i then convert to ip addresses. The packet is composed of 9 bytes. 4 for the first address, then 1 for a mask and another 4 bytes for the second address.

The strange thing that happens is that the 2 byte of the 2 address print the wrong value. why?

```
package net.floodlightcontroller.openlisp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;

import net.floodlightcontroller.packet.IPv4;

public class UdpServerCp extends Thread {

    protected OFLISPRules oflr = OFLISPRules.getInstance();
    private static UdpServerCp instance;
    private int priority = 3;

    public static synchronized UdpServerCp getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
        instance = new UdpServerCp();
        return instance;
    }

    public void run() {

        OpenlispHandler oh = OpenlispHandler.getInstance();

        byte[] receiveData = new byte[9];
        DatagramPacket receivePacket;
        System.out.println("Waiting to receive...");
        DatagramSocket serverSocket;
        try {
            serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(8888);

            while (true) {
                receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

                // if i receive a packet and it doesn't already have a flow rule
                // process it
                if ((receivePacket != null) && (oh.isNewOFRuleAdded() == false)){
                    byte[] bytes = receivePacket.getData();


                    //int eidInteger = ((int)bytes[3] << 8*3) + ((int)bytes[2] << 8*2) + ((int)bytes[1] << 8) + ((int) bytes[0]);
                    int eidInteger = ((int)bytes[0] << 8*3) + ((int)bytes[1] << 8*2) + ((int)bytes[2] << 8) + ((int) bytes[3]);
                    String eidAddressString = InetAddress.getByAddress(unpack(eidInteger)).getHostAddress();
                    System.out.println("buffer EID: " + eidAddressString);

                    int prefixInteger = (int) bytes[4];
                    System.out.println("buffer PREFIX: " + prefixInteger);

                    int rlocInteger = ((int)bytes[5] << 8*3) + ((int)bytes[6] << 8*2) + ((int)bytes[7] << 8) + ((int) bytes[8]);
                    String rlocAddressString = InetAddress.getByAddress(unpack(rlocInteger)).getHostAddress();
                    System.out.println("buffer RLOC: " + rlocAddressString);



                    IPv4 eidADD = new IPv4();
                    IPv4 rlocADD = new IPv4();
                    eidADD.setDestinationAddress(eidAddressString);
                    rlocADD.setDestinationAddress(rlocAddressString);

                    oflr.rlocOFRule(eidADD, prefixInteger, rlocADD, priority);
                    oh.setNewOFRuleAdded(true);
                    this.priority++;
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    byte[] unpack(int bytes) {
        return new byte[] { 
                (byte) ((bytes >>> 24) & 0xff),
                (byte) ((bytes >>> 16) & 0xff), 
                (byte) ((bytes >>> 8) & 0xff), 
                (byte) ((bytes) & 0xff) };
    }
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you'd show a [mcve]. We don't need to see any of the network code - just hard-code the 9 bytes you're receiving, show what you expect the result to be, and what the actual result is.

Comment: But you've ignored the rest of my suggestion, which is to replace the 83 lines of code which includes threading and networking with a short but complete example demonstrating the problem. Have you validated that you *actually* get a byte array of [153, 16, 17, 17, 28, 24, 25, 218, 27 ]? (In other words, you need to see whether the problem is your decoding or that you're not receiving the byte array you expect.)

Comment: ahh ok, ill debug and see what i actually get in bytes

Comment: I see you've now accepted an answer, but please take this as a learning experience for how to ask a good question.

Comment: will do. thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you cast a byte to an int you may get negative numbers. Since 218 is a negative byte value this happens here and causes the previous byte to be decremented.

```
int rlocInteger = ((int)bytes[5] << 8*3) + ((int)bytes[6] << 8*2) + ((int)bytes[7] << 8) + ((int) bytes[8]);
```

To fix this, mask with 0xff, for example: `((bytes[5]&0xff) << 8*3)`

Comment: Works great now. thanks Henry. that was the problem. i was sending unsigned int and i was not considering the negatives.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason for going through an integer to get 4 bytes out of a 9-byte array, just copy the sub-array you need. Something like:

```
byte[] bytes = receivePacket.getData();
String eidAddressString = InetAddress.getByAddress(Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 0, 4)).getHostAddress();
System.out.println("buffer EID: " + eidAddressString);

int prefixInteger = (int) bytes[4];
System.out.println("buffer PREFIX: " + prefixInteger);

String rlocAddressString = InetAddress.getByAddress(Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 5, 9)).getHostAddress();
System.out.println("buffer RLOC: " + rlocAddressString);
```